# Maven Shade Plugin SHA1 digest error

Tags: maven, maven-shade-plugin, uberjar

I have a maven module using maven shade plugin which is building an uber.jar. The module itself has no source in it yet builds a jar (local.jar). Now when i run mvn install, the build works as expected generates the shaded(uber.jar) jar, but i had to exclude all transitive dependencies , so set 
"minimizejar" to true. Now the build picks the empty local.jar and tries to minimize it and in the process throws an exception

" Error creating shaded jar: SHA1 digest error for version.txt"

Here is the shade plugin declaration in my pom

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
    <execution>
        <id>shade-uber</id>
        <phase>package</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>shade</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
        <minimizeJar>true</minimizeJar>
       <shadedArtifactAttached>false</shadedArtifactAttached>
        <filters>
        <filter>
            <artifact>*:*</artifact>
            <excludes>
                <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
                <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
                <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
                <exclude>META-INF/*</exclude>
            </excludes>
        </filter>
    </filters>
          <outputFile>target/uber.jar</outputFile>
          <artifactSet>
            <includes>
        <include>abc.*:*</include>
    </includes>
```

I also tried generating a local.pom instead, but the shade step gives a null pointer exception this time
I dont understand how to exclude local.jar from the shade process. local.jar is empty and not signed.

Any help here is much appreciated.

Comment: As best I can tell minimizeJar is buggy and you just have to do without it.